# How can I make servers separatedl to main server and image store server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Now I'm trying to make app, in which users can upload their images as much as they want.
The problem is the number of images.
My app will be almost like image uploader so that there will be huge data traffic.

now I'm using the gem called 'paperclip', and renting 1 VPS server.
If I'm going to rent another VPS only for images to be stored, how can I archive one is normal app except it passes only image data to another vps.
Then how the image server can receive data from main server.

Anyone has done this kind of clustering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what service provider you are using but you may want to look at [Fog](http://fog.io/storage/), it works very well for remote storage to many providers and integrates well with Paperclip and Carrierwave. As far as setup, you will have to follow instructions for whatever provider you have. Good luck!